# Fancybox 3.5 - How to make a modal iframe use the source URL?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm building my portfolio home page along with a number of project pages. When a user clicks on project links, Fancybox (3.5.7) opens an iframe modal popup, pulling in content from the respective project page url.

The issue I have is that the URL becomes `portfolio.com/#data-fancybox-1`. Successive links lead to `#data-fancybox-2` and so on.

I'd like the URL to just be source URL that Fancybox is pulling the content from - ie: `portfolio.com/project-page`. On exiting the modal, the original `portfolio.com/` should return.

It sounds so simple but I've scoured through Fancybox documentation and all over stack overflow and github for info on this.. Anything close to this seems to be years ago for outdated versions and require cookies.

If anyone knows how to best do this in 2020 I'd love any help or guidance

Answer (score 0):

Just open fancybox manually when needed. There are plenty of demos on docs.